# How to replace a node in XML using Python with value fetched from database using minidom?

Tags: python, minidom

I am very new to Python and got stuck to a point. I am trying to replace selective nodes in an XML document with corresponding values from MS SQL Server. I am supposed to use only minidom to achieve the same. The database table consists buyer information in Polish which is unicoded and i am supposed to replace the English information in existing XML with Polish data.
Following is the structure of XML document where changes are supposed to happen:

```
<INVPARTNER>
            <INVOICE_BUYER>XXXXX</INVOICE_BUYER>          (Unique Customer ID)
            <INVOICE_PAYERNO>92254</INVOICE_PAYERNO>     
            <INVOICE_BUYERVATID>BLAH</INVOICE_BUYERVATID>
            <buyer1>ABC</buyer1>                     (Customer name 1: DB Value CUSTNAME1)
            <buyer2/>                                (Customer name 2: DB Value CUSTNAME2)
            <buyer3>XYZ</buyer3>                     (Customer name 3: DB Value CUSTADDR1)
            <buyer4/>                                (Customer name 4: DB Value CUSTADDR2)
            <buyer5>PQR</buyer5>
            <buyer6>ITALY</buyer6>
            <buyer7/>
            <buyer8></buyer8>
            <buyer9/>
            <buyer10/>
```

I have written following code to achieve the same but failing to do so:

```
import pyodbc
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
docTypes = {'INVOICE':['INVOICE_BUYER', 'INVOICE_CONSIGNEE']}
changeValues = {'INVOICE':{"buyer1":'CUSTNAME1', "buyer2":'CUSTNAME2', "buyer3":'CUSTADDRESS1', "buyer4":'CUSTADDRESS2'}}
dom = parse("Print.xml")
type = dom.getElementsByTagName('DocumentID')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
print type
i = 0
CONN_STR = 'DSN=dsn;;DB=test_DB;UID=usr;PWD=passwrd'
db = pyodbc.connect(CONN_STR)
c = db.cursor()
print docTypes['INVOICE']
if docTypes.has_key(type):
   #iterator = len(docTypes[type])
   for i in range(0,len(docTypes[type])):
      for tag in dom.getElementsByTagName(docTypes[type][i]):
         name = tag.childNodes[0]
         c.execute (u"select CUSTOMER, ADDRESSTYPE, CUSTNAME1, CUSTNAME2, CUSTADDRESS1, CUSTADDRESS2 from CUSTADDR_UC where 'CUSTOMER' = ('%u')", name.nodeValue)
         rows = c.fetchall()
         for key in changeValues[type].iterkeys():
            print dom.getElementsByTagName(key)[0].toxml()
            for row in rows:
               if dom.getElementsByTagName(key)[0].toxml() is not None:
                  change = dom.getElementsByTagName(key)[0].toxml()
                  change.nodeValue = unicode(row.changeValue[type][key])
open("D:\\Shantanu\\done2.xml","w").write(dom.toxml("utf-8"))
```

Though there is no any error in the code, it is not even replacing the node value as well. Can you please help me if anything is wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you can do an in place update of nodes in minidom. You will have to create whole document with new updated value.

Comment: @Vinayak: I have created the new document as: open("D:\\Shantanu\\done2.xml","w").write(dom.toxml("utf-8"))

Comment: I didn't mean the file document that you are creating new, I meant the xml document in memory you need to create with updated value because minidom won't support in place changing values of node. You can look at xml.etree.ElementTree package for same.

Comment: @VinayakKolagi>> oh! i was explicitly asked to use minidom.. i'll try to use ElementTree in testing area..